What was the point of all those TV screens at the Architect’s office?
In The Matrix Reloaded, what was the point of all those TV screens at the Architect’s office?


it symbolizes that he can see everything, for him the world is nothing more than a tv show.

Welcome to the site.  The edit someone made to your post made conform to our typical format here on the site.  We don't typically include the movie name in the title (that's what the tag is for).  Please don't just automatically roll back to your original version.

The question may be getting downvotes because it might be considered a bit brief or likely to result in answers that are opinions - however I don't see why someone could not propose some analysis on the purpose of the screens in the office.

I asked question about the thing but what I am getting is only suggestions please give me explanation my question and that's it.

@A.bakker - Not true. We see him out in 'the world' at the end of the following film. Clearly he's capable of leaving.

@Valorum did i ever claim he wasn't able to leave?

@A.bakker - Your words were "...the world is nothing more than a tv show." Clearly this is a TV show that he can walk around in and interact with, just like real TV shows.

@Valorum interactive TV is a thing for a few years now :)

The problem, as Neo notes, is choice. In particular, the Architect, as a being of pure logic, has difficulty in understanding irrational decisions made by humans.

Oracle: Please… You and I may not be able to see beyond our own choices, but that man can’t see past any choices.
Neo: Why not?
Oracle: He doesn’t understand them – he can’t. To him they are variables in an equation. One at a time each variable must be solved and countered.

So what are the monitor screens? They represent  the Architect's models of what he expects Neo to do, based on predicted emotional responses to his own statements about Zion and the role of The One.
This is, in turn, presumably based on the way that other individuals in Neo's position have reacted (e.g. on being told that their worldview is a total fiction and that everyone they've ever known is about to die horribly). Some have displayed aggression, others indifference or depression or hysteria. The Architect evidently considers those all to be realistic conversational options.
As the conversation comes to a close, the choices lessen and the monitors start to consistently display Neo's actual responses.

NEO: There are only two possible explanations...
We move towards a specific Neo, centered among the others,  closing in on a single line of thought.
NEO: Either no one told me, or no-one knows.
We enter that monitor and turn to the Architect.
Matrix Reloaded Script

Once the Architect understands what decision Neo has made, even if he can't understand why, his deterministic model about Neo's behaviour start working accurately again.

From a purely functional perspective, it's also worth noting that these monitors are how the Architect observes the world of the Matrix. They first appeared in the police interrogation scene in the first film and when we leave the Architect, he's "returning his attention" to them to watch Trinity fight the agents.

Neo throws open the door and the Architect is flashed with light before returning his attention to the monitors-- Where Trinity is now found by the Agents, firing and running
as we enter the monitors--

